# Unable to make preoload function aware of content changes on store - sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

i need help, i've been struggling with this for days with no luck. I  modified the blog example to handle my proyects section. i managed to make it work from a  custom writable store file, I can make all the CRUD operations inside the store and they are updated on the components who need them. All except the [slug].svelte page.

seems that even the  [slug].JSON.js file has a subscription, the [slug].svelte context module is unable to get the store changes after they are made.

here is my [slug].JSON.js file.

```
import proyectos from "./_projectsStore.js";
let projects;
proyectos.subscribe(p => {
    projects = p;
})

const lookup = new Map();
projects.forEach(project => {
    lookup.set(project.slug, JSON.stringify(project));
});

export function get(req, res, next) {
    // the `slug` parameter is available because
    // this file is called [slug].json.js
    const { slug } = req.params;

    if (lookup.has(slug)) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        res.end(lookup.get(slug));
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            message: `Not found`
        }));
    }
}
```

for what i believe is a problem with the preload function that is not aware of changes after they are made.

```
<script context="module">
  export async function preload({ params, query }) {
    // the `slug` parameter is available because
    // this file is called [slug].html
    const res = await this.fetch(`portafolio/${params.slug}.json`);
    const data = await res.json();
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return { project: data };
    } else {
      this.error(res.status, data.message);
    }
  }
</script>
```

any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want your `lookup` map to always contain a mapping of slugs to projects that is kept up-to-date with the `proyectos` store.

In that case, the way you populate the map will only give you the first version at best (or maybe even fall with an error), because the map is not connected to the `proyectos` store by any means.

A way to connect them would be to populate the map inside the subscription function:

```js
// [slug].json.js
const lookup = new Map();
proyectos.subscribe(p => {
  lookup.clear();
  p.forEach(project => {
    lookup.set(project.slug, JSON.stringify(project));
  });
})
```

This way, the map will be repopulated every time the `proyectos` store changes, which will make your endpoint able to respond to changes.

Comment: thank you for your kind response. I'm still unable to make it work. still returns 404 when trying to reach the slug url.

I console.log(page)  on [slug].svelte context module; and i get the { slug: 'sample-project' } correctly. so i assume is a subscription issue on this page.

Comment: So the `context=module` script on `[slug].svelte` is executed? In that case a 404 is a strange error to receive. Perhaps you could update the question with more code of the slug page?